# Take 30 random elements from list

Tags: c#, list, random

I have a list of strings containing loads of hashtags with texts. 
ex #csharp #java ect. 
each hashtag is a own string in a List. I now want to randomly always console.writeline 30 items of that list.

List

```
List<string> Hashtags = new List<string>();
```

Writeline

```
 foreach (var x in Hashtags) {

                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
```

Ideally i never wanna have the same hashtag in the random 30.

Comment: All the 30 strings begin with "#"?

Comment: Where's your attempt at the problem? This is not a homework writing service.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin yep

Comment: @MischaMorf so you want to randomly select 30 elements from your list, correct? Are the list elements distinct?

Comment: @SteveTodd ive tried the following:
var shuffledcards = Hashtags.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var x in Hashtags) {
                if (i>30) {
                    Console.WriteLine(x);
                    i++;

                }
            }

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim var shuffledcards = Hashtags.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var x in Hashtags) {
                if (i>30) {
                    Console.WriteLine(x);
                    i++;

                }
            }

Comment: @MischaMorf - `Guid.NewGuid()` is only guaranteed to be unique, not random. You should always use a RNG and never `Guid` for randomness.

Comment: @Enigmativity thans didnt know that

Comment: @MischaMorf do not post attempt in comments. Update the question with those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try this:

```
var rnd = new Random();

foreach (var x in Hashtags.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(30))
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

This has `O(n^2)` complexity, but is easily readable.

If you want efficiency try a Fisher-Yates Shuffle, it's `O(n)`, but less readable:

```
var take = 30;

var rnd = new Random();

for (var i = 0; i < (Hashtags.Count < take ? Hashtags.Count : take); i++)
{
    var j = rnd.Next(Hashtags.Count);
    (Hashtags[i], Hashtags[j]) = (Hashtags[j], Hashtags[i]);
}

foreach (var x in Hashtags.Take(take))
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Keep in mind, though, that it's best to instantiate `Random` once per thread, so this would be a better way:

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static Random rnd = new Random();
```

Comment: The only negative is that you need to order the complete collection to pick 30 items.

Comment: @Magnus - That's true, but even with a list of 1_000_000 elements it takes less than half a second to sort on my computer. On a plus side it's guaranteed to finish and it will work with a source list that is smaller in size that the requested amount.

Comment: @Enigmativity Still, this is very short but HIGHLY inefficient solution. Not only you're sorting the whole collection, which is obviously a problem, also, even more - you don't need to sort it at all, you just need to shuffle a given number of items. Sorry but this shouldn't be an accepted answer.

Comment: @zhulien - I agree that it is inefficient. It's `O(n^2)`, but drop in a Fisher-Yates Shuffle and it becomes `O(n)`. It's not as readable, but it's a lot more efficient then than any method mentioned here so far.

Comment: @Enigmativity Not sure what you mean by 'but it's a lot more efficient then than any method mentioned here so far'. Did you check my solution before commenting?

Comment: @zhulien - No, you're right. I didn't check yours. You're right. Yours is more efficient.

Comment: @zhulien - I've updated mine. I feel I'm on par now. :-)

Comment: Why not use `Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Select(x => Hashtags[rnd.Next(0, Hashtags.Count)]);`;

Comment: @RandRandom - Because that doesn't ensure unique elements.

Comment: Could cheat with lazy evaluation of LINQ `Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue).Select(x => rnd.Next(0, list.Count - 1)).Distinct().Take(30).Select(x => list[x]);` though the beauty is gone :) - With a small test, this approach seems double as fast as your solution - though it's with 2.5 billion entries in the list we are talking about `4ms` vs `9ms` on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

This should do. It is efficient, as it shuffles only the required amount of items, not the whole collection. You pass how many elements you want to fetch from the array as parameter(`elementCount`).

```
private static Random randomGenerator = new Random();

static void Main()
{
    var hashtags = new List<string>() { "c#", "javascript", "ef", "asp.net" };

    var result = GetRandomItems<string>(hashtags, 2);

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> GetRandomItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, int elementCount)
{
    var collectionCount = collection.Count();

    if (elementCount > collectionCount)
    {
        elementCount = collectionCount;
    }

    var collectionCopy = collection.ToList();

    var randomIndex = randomGenerator.Next(0, collectionCopy.Count);

    for (var index = 0; index < elementCount; index++)
    {
        var tempElement = collectionCopy[index];

        collectionCopy[index] = collectionCopy[randomIndex];
        collectionCopy[randomIndex] = tempElement;

        randomIndex = randomGenerator.Next(index + 1, collectionCopy.Count);
    }

    return collectionCopy.Take(elementCount);
}
```

Comment: Nice. Instead of making a copy of the list, perhaps shuffling a `List<int>(collection.Count())` (to represent indexes) would be more efficient.

Comment: It's nice that it's only shuffling the required number of items.

Comment: (FYI, the comment about `.Select` was that you don't need it at all; `collection.ToList()` will return a copy of the `collection`)

Answer (score 0):

Call 30 times Random.next

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next

```
var random = new Random();

//calls this n times in a loop:
Console.writeline(Hashtags[random.next(Hashtags.Count])
```

Comment: This doesn't have any logic to stop getting the same hashtag twice since the `random.next` code can return the same value more than once.

Comment: @MischaMorf - This doesn't work if you're trying to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @Enigmativity i just remove the string from the string list after writing it out. Then it does:)

Comment: @MischaMorf - It's rather inefficient to resize arrays like that though.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working myself, little more verbose but hopefully easier to follow.

```
 var random = new Random();
 var uniques = Hashtags; 

 for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {  
     var index =  random.Next(0, uniques.Count());
     Console.WriteLine(uniques[index]);
     uniques.RemoveAt(index); 
 }
```

Comment: apologies - you posted this before my final edits. 

obviously you have to add some using statements at the top but I thought the IDE will at least give you that.

Comment: It still doesn't compile, even with your final edits.

Comment: sorry, i thought I posted a final edit but closed the tab first :)

Comment: @KrishanPatel this code will fail with a compilation error. In any case, `Count()` and `ToList()` aren't needed because `Hashtags` is a list already. `Count()` will call `.Lenght` internally. `ToList()` will create an expensive copy of the list

Comment: Also, there's no method `DateTime.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()` - it should be `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()`. Now even if you try to call `new Random(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds())` that's a syntax error. And even if it did work calling it that way is one thousand times worse than just calling `new Random()` (which uses `Environment.TickCount` internally).

Comment: Starting with `max=Hashtags.Length` means there's always a chance of producing an out-of-range index. It should be `var max=Hashtags.Length -1;`

Comment: If you make `Random` a static field of the class and only initialize it once, you can use it as often as you like and will get random numbers. It's almost never a good idea to initialize `Random` inside the method that's using it. Also, `Random` uses the system clock for a seed value by default.

Comment: For multiple executions one should use the *same* instance of `Random` instead of trying to create a new one or far worse, using seconds as the seed. Using seconds means that for an entire second the *same* sequence of numbers will be produced.

Comment: Are you intending `var uniques = Hashtags` to be a **reference** copy of `Hashtags` or creating a clone?